# how do i set JAVA_HOME in bash?

Tags: java, linux, bash, cygwin

my host system is windows 7

I am trying to get this to work in **CYGWIN**.

I need to set an environment variable called **JAVA_HOME** to be `c/program files (x86)/java/jre7`

here's what i tried:

```
$myjava=cat c/program\ files\ \(x86\)/java/jre7
export JAVA_HOME=myjava
```

but i am getting:

> line 9: c/program files (x86)/java/jre7: No such file or directory
>   Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export JAVA_HOME=c:/program\ files\ \(x86\)/java/jre7
```

Answer (score 2):

Two errors: First, you're attempting to execute "`c/program files (x86)/java/jre7`" with a wierdly set one-shot variable, second, it looks like you're using bourne-shell semantics: first you must set variable, then you can export it.

The line `$myjava=cat c/program\ files\ (x86)/java/jre7` says *take the variable named "myjava", extract the value (wait, that var doesn't exist? well, the value will be the empty string...), use that value as the name of a variable, and set *that* variable to have the value "cat". Don't actually set this in the shell environment, we'll run "c/program\ files\ (x86)/java/jre7" and set this as an extra variable in that command's environment*. That's why you're getting "c/program files (x86)/java/jre7: No such file or directory".

The line `export JAVA_HOME=myjava`, in bash I would say that means *create/set a variable named `JAVA_HOME`, set it to the string "myjava", and flag it as an exported variable*. The error message "Error: JAVA_HOME is not set." either means that you need to break it up (not using bash?), as `JAVA_HOME=$myjava; export JAVA_HOME`, or it means that JAVA_HOME is not set *to anything that makes sense*, and if you fix the first line, it'll all get better.

Answer (score 1):

@BMargulies Answer has provided a solution.  But I think it is relevant to understand why what you did was wrong ... so that next time you can take (at least) a better stab at getting it correct.

Looking at your first command line ...

```
$myjava=cat c/program\ files\ \(x86\)/java/jre7
```

There are a number things wrong with that.  First, the syntax for setting a shell variable is:

```
<name>=<word>
```

so what you would actually be doing in the first line is follows:

1. It is setting a variable with a some unknown variable name to the string "cat":

   - The variable name is unknown because it depends on the *prior* value of the "myjava" variable.  (The utterance "$myjava" says "interpolate the value of the 'myjava' variable here".)
   - The reason that it is setting the variable to "cat" is that "cat" is the first word after the "=".
2. Then, it is attempting to run the rest of the line (i.e. "c/program\ files\ (x86)/java/jre7") as a command.  But it isn't a command: it is a directory.  And that's the most likely source of the "Not Found" error message you are seeing.

On top of that, you seem to be *trying* to use the "cat" command for something.  The "cat" command (in that form) reads the contents of a file and writes it to standard output.

1. You don't have a file.  You are looking at a directory.
2. You don't care about the contents of the directory.  (And that's not how you would access it ...)
3. You are not looking at standard out.

In short, "cat" is completely unnecessary here.  You just want the *pathname* for the directory.  So the correct form of the first line would be:

```
 myjava=c/program\ files\ \(x86\)/java/jre7
```

or using quotation marks:

```
 myjava="c/program files (x86)/java/jre7"
```

or

```
 myjava='c/program files (x86)/java/jre7'
```

The three kinds of quoting all have the same effect.  They cause the stuff after the "=" to be parsed as a single `<word>`.  (There are differences in behaviour between the 3 quoting styles, but they don't matter here.)

The second line is actually close to what it needs to be.  You wrote:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=myjava
```

means set JAVA_HOME to the literal string "myjava" ... and export it.  But you want to use the value of the shell variable named "myjava".  That is:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=$myjava
```

The "$myjava" says "interpolate the value of the variable 'myjava'" ... see above.

---

@BMargulies answer combines the two lines into on, and does away with the (unnecessary) local variable "myjava".  That is the way I'd have done it too.